# Aniqroid library compilation

Tags: java, android

I want to change source code of aniqroid library https://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/

I create java application, add android library to "Java Build Path" and after that "Export".
Then add jar to my android project.

Problem is that when I start my application it crashes with ClassNotFoundException of "com.sileria.android.Application" that is used in the manifest.
If I just add source code to my application, then it works fine.

I suppose that I just have lack of knowledge about building. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any help!

**UPD:**

LOGCAT:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(9646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sileria.android.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sileria.android.Application in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp.apk]
    E/AndroidRuntime(9646): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sileria.android.Application in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk]
```

Manifest:

```
     <application
        ...
        android:name="com.sileria.android.Application"
        ...
     </application>
```

Solved by creating library project, but it is still interesting how to make jar.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output to check out where the breakage is??

Comment: Is com.sileria.android.Application used in the manifest of your own application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have built android application using jdk 1.6, but aniqroid library using 1.7. Changing to 1.6 solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm okay I see after viewing the jar archive of library what the problem might be..

I take it you want to customize to use in own app rather than change library code

You will the Application class in the library aniqroid and the Application class mention in  the android manifest will be the one in your main project with your app package naming scheme..

When you first type YourApp extends Application 
the IDE will give you two choices, you want the second choice which will be your application class from the library you are attempting to use.